# Routing to a floating IP between 2 servers on different networks

Tags: routing, router, solaris

I have two servers in two different network subnets, there is a heartbeat between the servers and they automatically select active / standby. the active server will have a floating IP assigned to one of it's interfaces.

My problem is: how can I program my routers to route traffic to the active server?

Multiple static routes will not simply work, because the next hop address (the actual IP of the NIC with the floating IP will not be down in the server is in standby mode)

Network 1 is `10.74.13.0/24`

Network 2 is `10.74.23.0/24`

NIC 1 IP is `10.74.13.17/24`

NIC 2 IP is `10.74.23.17/24`

Floating IP is `10.74.3.3/32`

Network 1 can ping 2 without any issues.
The routers are cisco and servers are on Solaris.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for the servers to reconfigure the routers?

Comment: no, the server only controls if the floating IP is on or off, doesn't really interact with the routers

Comment: How exactly is the floating IP supposed to actually float? The standard method is for the CIDR to be something with on-link determination, if you're going to use a /32, the servers themselves would need to speak a routing protocol.

Comment: The Server has a software handling the floating IP so that only one of them has it at any time. if you make a static route to the floating IP with the server interface as the next hop, the connection will be ok, given that the static route is to the active server. In the standard case both servers are in the same subnet, and also the floating ip is in the same range, but my case different as I have them in different networks.

Comment: Well that's quite messy; any chance those 3 address spaces are on the same Layer 2 network? (ie, same VLAN/Switch)

Comment: If all were on the same range then there would be no problem, but the sites are interconnected via L3 routers and each has it's own IP range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the solution developer and confirmed that the floating IP mechanism can only work if both server are located on the same network segment.

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is to add another system (can be an old, slow one) in Network1. This system detects the breakdown of server1 (either by itself or it gets notified by server2 when it takes over) and takes over the floating IP. It also does NAT for this IP so that all traffic for server1 is forwarded to server2.

I have no experience with heartbeat. This would work only if the apps don't care about the IP address. And if there is enough available bandwidth between the subnets. The address problem could be solved by having another NAT system in Network2. More points of failure, of course.

Comment: Adding a server or other network element is not an option now, the question more specifically is there any method to configure routing  so that one of two routes in selected depending on the reachability of the IP at any time. BFD would be an answer if it was supported by the server

Comment: There might be alternatives, but as there is no way for the router to detect this floating IP adding another system to the network is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what expected too. I'll dig deeper to find a work around. my ideas now are: routing from the server it self to the remote server if it is in stadby mode by adding a static route. Or, a VPN maybe..